# java - fields of volatile object cannot be visible?

Tags: java, volatile

AnyBody have some demo code to prove  this, PLZ ？？？？

I see the answer 'NO' from [this article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/volatile-ref-object.html).

But I don't understand the example of this article. The both read & write thread have started, then join ??

```java
writerThread.start();
readerThread.start();
writerThread.join();
readerThread.join();
```

I think w.start -> w.join -> r.start -> r.join  should be right. But with this order, the result is different.:(

Comment: `w.start -> w.join -> r.start -> r.join` would essentially make it synchronous as yu are starting `w` then waiting for it to finish before starting `r`

Comment: The article is saying correct, the fields will be visible to all threads, the thing is that the declared field will only be accessed or written one at a time.

Comment: There is a 1us sleep in `w`. Maybe readThread  read a & b during this time, so the result of a&b is different. It cannot prove the title.

Comment: *java - fields of volatile object cannot be visible* Is visible anywhere - beeing volatile has nothing to do with visibility. What you see - is a different story.

Comment: you are right. This article just proves atomicity, not visibility.